# conditional insert into mysql

Tags: mysql, insert, subquery, case

I am quite newbie with MySQL (5.1) and I don't achieve to do a conditional "insert into".
For each record, I want to insert into the same columns (1 and 2) from an empty/destination table, either 2 fields (A and B) or 2 other fields (C and D) from a source table containing several records.
Here my query:

```
INSERT INTO DB.table_destination(field1, field2)
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN fieldAA='value1' THEN (
            SELECT fieldA, fieldB   
            FROM DB.table_source<BR>
            )
        ELSE (
            SELECT fieldC, fieldD
            FROM DB.table_source
            )
    END
FROM db.table_source
```

Note that the fieldAA belongs to the table_source too.
I have an error around the second SELECT. Depending on some tiny changes in my script, it sometimes complains that I have more than one row.
I am stuck on that issue for a while, so I will greatly appreciate your help.

[EDIT]

Thanks a lot for your advices! It works perfectly with this simple example.
However, my study case is in the real life a bit more complex, as I have to deal with 3 source tables, including one condition (JOIN) between tables_source_1 and table_source_2, and one spatial function between table_source_1 and table_source_3.

Here my query that returns me the result from only one condition:

```
INSERT INTO test.OBSERVATION (CODE_INSEE,ID_SITE,LONGWGS84,LATWGS84)
    SELECT
        CASE METHODE_LOC WHEN '13' THEN insee_zerofill ELSE INSEE_zero END,
        CASE METHODE_LOC WHEN '13' THEN '' ELSE ID_SITE END,
        CASE METHODE_LOC WHEN '13' THEN GPS_TEL_LNG ELSE LONG_LIEU_DIT END,
        CASE METHODE_LOC WHEN '13' THEN GPS_TEL_LAT ELSE LAT_LIEU_DIT END
    FROM odk.test_insee, odk.site_clone RIGHT JOIN odk.DEMO_OISEAUX9_FULL_CORE ON odk.site_clone.ID_SITE=odk.DEMO_OISEAUX9_FULL_CORE.SITE_OBS
    WHERE odk.GISWithin(GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',GPS_TEL_LNG,' ',GPS_TEL_LAT,')')), SHAPE)
```

Tables details
1) odk.test_insee contains SHAPE (geometry used in the spatial function GISWithin) and insee_zerofill.
2)    DEMO_OISEAUX9_FULL_CORE contains GPS_TEL_LNG & GPS_TEL_LAT (filled when METHODE_LOC is equal to 13), ID_SITE (filled when METHODE_LOC is different from 13).
3) odk.site_clone contains INSEE_zero, LONG_LIEU_DIT, LAT_LIEU_DIT.

I tried to set a CASE in the WHERE condition to tell it to perform the function only when ID_SITE is null, but without success so far.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

[EDIT 2]
Now, it works! I should have repeated the specific condition within the CASE for EACH field to select, as followed:

```
SELECT
    CASE METHODE_LOC WHEN '13' THEN 
        (SELECT insee_zerofill
        FROM odk.test_insee, odk.DEMO_OISEAUX9_FULL_CORE
        WHERE odk.GISWithin(GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',`GPS_TEL_LNG`,' ',`GPS_TEL_LAT`,')')), SHAPE)  )
    ELSE 
        (SELECT INSEE_zero
        FROM odk.site_clone RIGHT JOIN odk.DEMO_OISEAUX9_FULL_CORE 
        ON odk.site_clone.ID_SITE=odk.DEMO_OISEAUX9_FULL_CORE.SITE_OBS
        WHERE odk.DEMO_OISEAUX9_FULL_CORE.SITE_OBS is not NULL  )
    END,
    CASE METHODE_LOC WHEN '13' THEN ''
    ELSE 
        (SELECT ID_SITE
        FROM odk.site_clone RIGHT JOIN odk.DEMO_OISEAUX9_FULL_CORE 
        ON odk.site_clone.ID_SITE=odk.DEMO_OISEAUX9_FULL_CORE.SITE_OBS
        WHERE odk.DEMO_OISEAUX9_FULL_CORE.SITE_OBS is not NULL  )
    END,
    CASE METHODE_LOC WHEN '13' THEN 
        (SELECT GPS_TEL_LNG
        FROM odk.test_insee, odk.DEMO_OISEAUX9_FULL_CORE
        WHERE odk.GISWithin(GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',`GPS_TEL_LNG`,' ',`GPS_TEL_LAT`,')')), SHAPE)  )
    ELSE 
        (SELECT LONG_LIEU_DIT
        FROM odk.site_clone RIGHT JOIN odk.DEMO_OISEAUX9_FULL_CORE 
        ON odk.site_clone.ID_SITE=odk.DEMO_OISEAUX9_FULL_CORE.SITE_OBS
        WHERE odk.DEMO_OISEAUX9_FULL_CORE.SITE_OBS is not NULL  )
    END,
    CASE METHODE_LOC WHEN '13' THEN 
        (SELECT GPS_TEL_LAT
        FROM odk.test_insee, odk.DEMO_OISEAUX9_FULL_CORE
        WHERE odk.GISWithin(GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',`GPS_TEL_LNG`,' ',`GPS_TEL_LAT`,')')), SHAPE)  )
    ELSE 
        (SELECT LAT_LIEU_DIT
        FROM odk.site_clone RIGHT JOIN odk.DEMO_OISEAUX9_FULL_CORE 
        ON odk.site_clone.ID_SITE=odk.DEMO_OISEAUX9_FULL_CORE.SITE_OBS
        WHERE odk.DEMO_OISEAUX9_FULL_CORE.SITE_OBS is not NULL  )
    END
FROM odk.DEMO_OISEAUX9_FULL_CORE ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this wawy for case

```
INSERT INTO DB.table_destination(field1, field2) 
SELECT CASE fieldAA   WHEN 'value1' THEN fieldA  ELSE fieldC END ,
       CASE fieldAA   WHEN 'value1'  THEN fieldB  ELSE fieldD END 
FROM db.table_source
```

If i understand correctly you question and you want perform your insert select only if ID_SITE is null  then you should use

```
INSERT INTO test.OBSERVATION (CODE_INSEE,ID_SITE,LONGWGS84,LATWGS84)
SELECT
    CASE METHODE_LOC WHEN '13' THEN insee_zerofill ELSE INSEE_zero END,
    CASE METHODE_LOC WHEN '13' THEN '' ELSE ID_SITE END,
    CASE METHODE_LOC WHEN '13' THEN GPS_TEL_LNG ELSE LONG_LIEU_DIT END,
    CASE METHODE_LOC WHEN '13' THEN GPS_TEL_LAT ELSE LAT_LIEU_DIT END
FROM odk.test_insee, odk.site_clone RIGHT JOIN odk.DEMO_OISEAUX9_FULL_CORE ON odk.site_clone.ID_SITE=odk.DEMO_OISEAUX9_FULL_CORE.SITE_OBS
WHERE odk.GISWithin(GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',GPS_TEL_LNG,' ',GPS_TEL_LAT,')')), SHAPE)
AND ID_SITE is null ;
```

you can use both case when is null

```
INSERT INTO DB.table_destination(field1, field2) 
SELECT CASE fieldAA   WHEN is null THEN fieldA  ELSE fieldC END ,
       CASE fieldAA   WHEN 'value1'  THEN fieldB  ELSE fieldD END 
FROM db.table_source
```

or ifnull

```
INSERT INTO DB.table_destination(field1, field2) 
SELECT ifnull( fieldAA, your_column_for_null) ,
       CASE fieldAA   WHEN 'value1'  THEN fieldB  ELSE fieldD END 
FROM db.table_source
```

Comment: I edited my question based on your advices few days ago, but I am still stuck because of the functions I have to use in the WHERE condition. May I have extra help please? Thanks!

Comment: You want performe the select only if the ID_SITE  is null? ii have update the answer

Comment: Not exactly. I have 1 main table (DEMO_OISEAUX) where the records are filled from a form, I want to INSERT those records into a new table (OBSERVATION) and fill the CODE_INSEE, LONGWGS84 and LATWGS84 fields using values EITHER from the site_clone table (when Methode_loc is NOT equal to 13 meaning ID_SITE is NOT null) using a JOIN function, OR from the test_insee table (when Methode_loc = 13 meaning ID_SITE is null) using the GISWithin function. If I add "AND ID_SITE is null" as suggested then it will only consider one of the two conditions in the CASE (when Methode_loc=13). Thanks in advance!

Comment: If i understand correctly your last commet seeem you want select where id_site is null or id_site is not  null  .. then you want select ever . ..? .. .

Comment: Not sure to get your question, but basically, I want to insert either some specific fields that require a JOIN ON when id_site is not null, or insert other fields that require a personnalized function (GISwithin) when id_site is null. In other words, I would like somehow to put the JOIN condition and the GISWithin function within the CASE. Is it possible using IF ELSE as a procedure rather than a CASE statement?

Comment: I have update the answer with a brief suggestion for case and ifnull .. hope this is useful

Comment: It did not really solved my problem, but it made me think twice and I finally solved my issue by understanding the code error I got sometimes: "operand should contain 1 column(s)". I have edited my initial question with a solution. Thanks a lot!